# java socket right way to send different message

Tags: java, sockets

I try to send different message from socket, but the result isn't as I think( like count up as everyone does), I'm not sure the reason.

When I use a variable to test the number of returning data, the result in first time is right, but it may skip or do nothing after first time, just like `int test=0; test++;` and the result of `test` should be `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`( like first send) but it become to `1 2 2 4 5 6 7 7 9`(when I resend socket message).

My code is:

In main.java:

```
static DatagramSocket socket2;
static boolean isRun=true;
static String sends="message#";
static int test=0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        socket2 = new DatagramSocket(10000);
        socket2.setBroadcast(true);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Server side problem occured: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    SendType1();
}

public static void SendType1(){
    test=0;
    sends = "message#";
    listen();
    SocketTest net= new SocketTest();
    net.sendMessage(sends);
}

public static void SendType2(){
    test=0;
    sends = "message2#";
    listen2();
    SocketTest net= new SocketTest();
    net.sendMessage(sends);
}

public static void listen() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try{

                byte[] recvBuf = new byte[1024];
                while (isRun) {
                    DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
                    try{
                        socket2.receive(packet2);
                        String message = new String(trimByte(packet2.getLength(),packet2.getData()));
                        if(message.startsWith("RE_" + sends)){
                            System.out.println(test+":"+message);   // the result doesn't as I think
                            test++;
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        System.out.println("Cannot receive package: " + ex.getMessage());
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Server side problem occured: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

public static void listen2() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                byte[] recvBuf = new byte[1024];

                while (true) {
                    DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
                    try{
                        socket2.receive(packet2);
                        String message = new String(trimByte(packet2.getLength(),packet2.getData()));
                        if(message.startsWith("RE_" + sends)){
                            // do something
                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        System.out.println("Cannot receive package: " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }

            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Server side problem occured: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private static byte[] trimByte(int length, byte[] tmp){
    byte[] ok=new byte[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        ok[i]=tmp[i];
    }
    return ok;
}
```

And SocketTest.java:

```
public class SocketTest {
DatagramSocket socket;
static List<String[]> listNet = new ArrayList<String[]>();
public SocketTest(){
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        socket.connect(InetAddress.getByName("255.255.255.255"), 10000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Connection failed. " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void sendMessage(String message){
    byte[] buf= message.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet;
    try{
        packet= new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
        socket.send(packet);
        //System.out.println("Socket send datas.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Sending failed. " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

I use `tabbedPane` as the UI to send different message, but I think that part is easy and isn't influence the problem, just like user change tab to 'Type1' to send message as 'message#' and change tab to 'Type2' to send message as 'message2#'.

The message I receive is right, but I need the variable `test` to show correct components( like buttons and labels), if `test` isn't as count up, I cannot set my layout properly.

Do I use wrong way to send different message?
I don't find any question as my `test` result( or I mislead the main problem by myself).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 'doesn't as I think` isn't a problem description. It isn't even English actually.

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault that I should only use one thread for receiving message instead using many thread for each different sending, and I should determine the returning message by `if`,`else`. The counter(variable `test`) may be given to different sending, too!

So I just change the main.java code to:

```
static DatagramSocket socket2;
static JFrame demo = new JFrame();
static JPanel myPanel=new JPanel();
static JPanel myPanel2=new JPanel();
static JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
static JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(tabbedPane);
static boolean isRun=true;
static int test=0;
static int test2=0;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    demo.setSize(600, 300);
    demo.setTitle("Test");
    demo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    try{
        socket2 = new DatagramSocket(10000);
        socket2.setBroadcast(true);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Server side problem occured: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
    SendMsg("message#");
    // Part of tabbedPane to change sending message
    tabbedPane.addTab("Type1", myPanel);
    myPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    tabbedPane.addTab("Type2", myPanel2);
    myPanel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            if(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
                SendMsg("message#");
            }else if(tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() == 1){
                SendMsg("message2#");
            }
        }
    });
    demo.getContentPane().add(pane);
    demo.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    demo.setVisible(true);
}

public static void SendMsg(String data){
    test2=0;
    myPanel.removeAll();
    myPanel.revalidate();
    demo.repaint();
    listen();
    SocketTest net= new SocketTest();
    net.sendMessage(data);
}

public static void listen() {
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try{
                byte[] recvBuf = new byte[1024];

                while (isRun) {
                    DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(recvBuf, recvBuf.length);
                    try{
                        socket2.receive(packet2);
                        String message = new String(trimByte(packet2.getLength(),packet2.getData()));
                        if(message.startsWith("RE_message#")){

                            test2++;
                            System.out.println(test2);          // the counter is okay now

                        }else if(message.startsWith("RE_message2#")){

                            test++;
                            System.out.println(test+");         // the counter is okay now

                        }
                    }catch(Exception ex){
                        System.out.println("Cannot receive package: " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println("Server side problem occured: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }.start();
}

private static byte[] trimByte(int length, byte[] tmp){
    byte[] ok=new byte[length];
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        ok[i]=tmp[i];
    }
    return ok;
}
```

So I guess I use two thread then each thread influence each other that cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just hope I have the right direction of solving the problem :)